# jQuery slider: show values that are multiples of 10?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I'm using the [jQuery ui slider,](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/) set up as follows:

```
 $("#unicornSlider").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 500,
    values: [0, 500]
  });
```

It works pretty well, but the range is set by default to every natural number - so when sliding I get values such as 61-403.

Anyone know how to set it so the values increase in multiples of 10, say? So values such as 60-400? This would work a lot better for a price slider.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the step property:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#option-step

```
$("#unicornSlider").slider({
  range: true,
  min: 0,
  max: 500,
  step: 10,
  values: [0, 500]
});
```

Comment: Can I give different step for different ranges? e.g. 10 for [0-200] and 100 for [201 - 500] ? in a single slider?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for the step option:

```
 $("#unicornSlider").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 500,
    values: [0, 500],
    step: 10
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `step` option.  http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#option-step